# Why am I having extra spaces in my Grid Items?

Tags: css, reactjs

I wanna know why there's extra space in my grid items although I did not set any height to each component? If you look closely, contents in 'nav' and 'footer'  area is not centered. [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLNFW.jpg) [website with grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAq25.png) (See 1st & 2nd pictures attached)  My goal is to set my 'nav' to its min-content and 'aside' will take the available row spaces. [idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNFZm.png) (See 3rd picture attached)

I'm using Grid components in ChakraUI.

Here's my layout code in App.jsx:

```
function App() {
  const [courseQuery, setCourseQuery] = useState({});
  return (
    <Grid
      h="100vh"
      gap={2}
      templateAreas={{
        base: ` "main" "footer"`,
        md: `"nav main" "aside main" "footer footer"`,
      }}
      templateColumns={{
        base: "1fr",
        md: "0.3fr 1fr",
      }}
    >
      <Show above="md">
        <GridItem borderRadius={10} p={6} area="nav" bg="gray.800">
          <Nav />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem borderRadius={10} py={6} pl={6} area="aside" bg="gray.800">
          <Aside/>
        </GridItem>
      </Show>
      <GridItem
        borderRadius={10}
        px={6}
        pt={6}
        area="main"
        bg={{ base: "gray.900", md: "gray.800" }}
      >
        <Stack h="85vh" overflow={"auto"} spacing={20}>
          <Hero />
          <ProjectGrid />
        </Stack>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem p={6} area="footer" bg="gray.800">
        <Footer />
      </GridItem>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default App;
```